# Swapping rows of a Theano symbolic matrix

Tags: python, theano

I am implementing parallel tempering Gibbs sampling using Theano. I am trying to create a Theano function that takes a matrix `X` and swaps some of its rows. I have a symbolic binary vector named `swaps` that denotes which rows should be swapped (i.e., if `swaps[i] == 1`, then `X[i]` and `X[i+1]` should be swapped). The order of swapping is not important for me.

I was trying to write a `theano.scan` that goes through the `swaps` vector and performs swapping of `X` row-by-row. The problem is that Theano doesn't allow doing something like `X[pos], X[pos + 1] = X[pos + 1], X[pos]` with symbolic variables. Here is a simple code snippet of what I am trying to do.

```
import numpy as np

import theano
import theano.tensor as T

def swap(swp, pos, idx):
    if swp: idx[pos], idx[pos + 1] = idx[pos + 1], idx[pos]
    return idx

max_length = 10
swaps = T.ivector('swaps')
idx   = T.ivector('idx')
pos   = T.iscalar('pos')

new_idx, updates = theano.scan(swap,
                               sequences=[swaps, T.arange(max_length)],
                               outputs_info=idx)

do_swaps = theano.function([swaps, idx], new_idx[-1], updates=updates)

idx_swapped = do_swaps(np.array([1, 1, 0, 1]), np.arange(5))
print idx_swapped
```

Any ideas on how I can do this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a really simple solution I found.

```
import numpy as np

import theano
import theano.tensor as T

def swap(swp, pos, X):
    return T.concatenate([X[:pos],X[[pos+swp]],X[[pos+1-swp]],X[pos+2:]])

max_length = 10
swaps = T.ivector('swaps')
pos   = T.iscalar('pos')
X     = T.vector('X')

new_X, _ = theano.scan(swap,
                       sequences=[swaps, T.arange(max_length)],
                       outputs_info=X)

do_swaps = theano.function([swaps, X], new_X[-1])

X_swapped = do_swaps(np.array([1, 1, 0, 1], dtype='int32'), np.arange(5))
print X_swapped
```

However, I am not sure how it is optimal or not for executing on a GPU.

Comment: you might want to do the swapping on a vector of indices first (`T.arange(X.shape[0])`) and then reindex the whole array at once (`X[p]`, where `p` is the permuted list of indices)